# Calling async web service fires callback handler twice

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, async-await

I'm calling a Web Service in a WP8 app using code obtained from a sample [here](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2013/01/using-asyncawait-with-webclient-in-windows-phone-8-or-taskcompletionsource-saves-the-day/):

```
public static Task<User> GetUser(string code)
{
      TaskCompletionSource<User> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<User>();

      WS.SoapClient ws = new WS.SoapClient();

      ws.MethodCompleted += (s, e) =>
      {
           if (e.Error == null)
           {
               tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
           }
           else
           {
               tcs.SetException(e.Error);
           }
       };

       ws.MethodAsync(code);

       return tcs.Task;
}
```

I'm `await`ing the `GetUser` method and this works fine.
The trouble is, the `MethodCompleted` handler fires twice for each `MethodAsync` invocation.

The second call has no controlling 'owner' and so, upon returning from `SetResult` the application itself throws an 'Object reference not set to an instance' exception.

Any ideas what is happening here, and how I overcome it?

Comment: What is SoapClient? The sample is about a completely different class (WebClient) that has been replaced with HttpClient in WP8 anyway. Could it be that `SoapClient` is raising the event twice? Is it a custom class?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.